# Automatic translation of accented characters in Winedt 7

Tags: characters, accents, winedt

I remember that a long time ago, when I was using Winedt (V5.0 I guess) it automatically replace some characters. For example, `ç` was replaced by `\c{c}` when I open the file.

Now, I need to do the same again. But I have Winedt 7.0 and I don't know how to translate all the accented characters automatically.

Any help?

Comment: what tex format are you using?  if it's latex, you needn't bother -- use the `inputenc` package and it'll all happen automagically.

Comment: You can activate/change translation tables in the options interface "Language, Unicode ...->translation tables".

Comment: @wasteofspace. I know that. But I must write in this way. I can not use any package. This is the rule (unfortunately).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Thanks. I'll try and come back later.

Answer (score 5):

I know that this answer comes a bit late and you probably have managed to do it already... (at that time I wasn't a TeX.SX user yet).

In WinEdt 7 (and above) all customizations are made from the `Options Interface` accessible from the `Options` menu, which looks like:

[image]

To achieve what you want, select the `Language, Unicode, Sorting, Translations...` branch and then double-click on `Translation Tables`: the script `TranslationTables.ini` will open.

Now, if you want to write `ç` in the editor, but you want the document to contain `\c{c}`, you have to enable (i.e. set `ENABLED=1`) the "translation table" named `TeX_Write`. If you want WinEdt to show `ç` when you open a document containing `\c{c}`, you have to enable the "translation table" named `TeX_Read`.

The same can be done for `.bib` files, enabling the "translation tables" named `BibTeX_Write` and `BibTeX_Read`.

Note that all of them are disabled by default since starting with version 7, WinEdt has Unicode support.

Of course all of them can be further customized to accomplish your personal needs, by adding or removing characters that have to be "translated".

When you've finished with it, remember to click the button `Load Current Script` in the toolbar of the `Options Interface` to apply the changes (the first one on the left). Note that if you skip this step nothing will be changed in your configuration...

Comment: @Sigur Did it work?

Comment: I'm on linux now. But next time when I use a Windows machine, I'll try it and inform you about the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in your preamble, you wouldn't need to convert those unicode characters at all. They would work as is.

Comment: Thanks. But please read my comment above.